# Exempt Visualforce Page From Validation Rule

Tags: visualforce, validation

I have the following Validation rule Active:

`Error Condition Formula:   ISPICKVAL(First_Ranking__c , "")`

When I try to submit the visualforce page I'm getting the validation error asking to select.

> Error: First Ranking: First Ranking is Required

Than  I have tried doing something required = false but still getting the validation error:

`<apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.First_Ranking__c}" required="false"  />`

So what I want to do is to ignore the validation error on the Visualforce page

Comment: It's not related, with your validation rule you have to provide value. At visualforce page you could force user to input field. you should deactivate your validation, or assign default value on page using apex:inputhidden

Comment: So you want to disable a `Validation Rule` only within the context of a `Visualforce Page`? Do you want to allow blank values or not?

Comment: @IlyaLepesh: I'm thinking the same way as you suggested which is deactivate but wondering is there any other way than deactivating

Comment: @AdrianLarson: disable a validation rule only wihtin the context of vfp, no blank values

Comment: Add another field, change validation to AND(ISPICKVAL(First_Ranking__c , ""),ISBLANK(field2)); pass field2 from page

Comment: to fake this. you can create another field and check value inside validation rule.

Comment: @Himanshu Great minds think alike. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson user let us think in that way... lol :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to disable the `Validation Rule` within the context of a `Visualforce Page`, your best bet is to create a checkbox along the lines of  `Is_Validation_Exempt__c`, and set it to `true` in your controller. Then change your rule to:

```
AND(NOT(Is_Validation_Exempt__c), ISPICKVAL(First_Ranking__c , ""))
```

To the above, you should add a `Workflow Rule` that updates the checkbox to false every time it gets checked. Since it fires after the `Validation Rule`, it will only affect subsequent saves.

Comment: N.B. the VR rule will use `is_validation_exempt__c` from the value in the database (i.e. saved by Controller) and hence will persist, essentially disabling the VR for this record, forever.

Comment: @cropredy Good point and an easy fix. Updated my answer. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @cropredy btw thanks for teaching me what `NB` stands for!

Comment: a small trade for your inspiring me to use the composition/fluent pattern :-)